# sudo for command with specific options

Tags: linux, sudo, root, access-control

Is it possible to configure `sudo` to get root privilege to a user for running a program with some special switches? for example, how can I configure it for user `admin` to run `netstat` command as the root with just switches `-r` and `-i`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the sudores file with `visudo` and add one line (or as many as you need) like in my example

```
admin ALL=/bin/netstat -r
admin ALL=/bin/netstat -i
```

`ALL=` can be a hostname, IP or localhost

The sudoers file is very well commented, at least in my CentOS

Comment: Does not work, I have tested it

Comment: What exactly have you tested?

Comment: Err, `netstat -r -i` doesn't really make sense...

Comment: Yes, I didn't knew when posted the answer at first, I rarely use netstat

Comment: this works for netstat, but my problem is with other commands which needs any argument. for example, `admin ALL=/bin/useradd -m` is not working because *admin* needs to add the name of new user. so. *admin*  cannot implement `useradd user-name -m` for example. @ecelis @lcd047

Comment: @Shahram Pezeshki: If you write it without options, any combinations of options will be allowed.  Also, please don't change the question after receiving answers.

Comment: @lcd047: yes, but I just want to let `admin' to run some options with root privilege

Comment: @Shahram Pezeshki: Please read again what I wrote.

Comment: You can use wildcards in the sudoers file

Answer (score 1):

Just add the options to the command:

```
admin       ALL     = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/netstat -i
admin       ALL     = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/netstat -r
```

Then `admin` will be able to run `sudo netstat -i`, but not `sudo netstat` etc.

Comment: this works for netstat, but my problem is with other commands which needs any argument. for example, admin ALL=/bin/useradd -m is not working because admin needs to add the name of new user. so. admin cannot implement useradd user-name -m for example.

Comment: Your question does not say anything about commands with parameters, the netstat example is missleading I believe

Answer (score 0):

Create a script

```
#!/bin/sh
netstat -i
```

call it supernetstat.sh
(don't forget permission 755,better 700)
then you can create an alias command on sudo
and give permission to user

Answer (score 0):

This line in the sudoers file works for me to allow a user to run useradd

```
someuser     ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd * -m
```

The * is a wildcard, there are other wildcard symbols, read `man sudoers`

Comment: if I use your policy,  I can use any options before -m, for example, `someuser` can run `sudo useradd new-user -d /home/newuser -c any-coments  -m`. but I want him to be able to use just -m.